# button doesn't change colour after scene building in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I would like to change the colour of a button after I build the scene.
I have to do a battleship. When I place a boat many buttons have to change their colours.

So, I have a function do to it and I test that. I filter the boxes contained in "oceanBoxes" by their coordinates and when I get true I call function putBoatInside.

```java
    private void placeGuiBoat(int x, int y, int direction, int size) {
        List<Integer> listBoxesBoatNeed;
        
        if(direction == HORIZONTAL) {

            listBoxesBoatNeed = IntStream.range(y,y+size).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
            try {
                listBoxesBoatNeed.forEach(e -> oceanBoxes.stream().filter(p->p.getX() == x && p.getY() == e).findFirst().orElse(null).putBoatInside());             
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
        
    }
```

And in Boxe class, I have this

```java
    public void putBoatInside() {
        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#000;");
    }
```

***EDIT***

Here the minimal reproducible example I made to solve it and see that the problem wasn't there.

Main

```java
package application;

import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import GUI.BtnOcean;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;



public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            
            GridPane root = new GridPane();
            
            BtnOcean btn = new BtnOcean(1,1);
            BtnOcean btn1 = new BtnOcean(1,2);
            BtnOcean btn2 = new BtnOcean(1,3);
            BtnOcean btn3 = new BtnOcean(1,4);
            BtnOcean btn4 = new BtnOcean(1,5);
    
            ArrayList<BtnOcean> ocean = new ArrayList<BtnOcean>(Arrays.asList(btn,btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4));
            
            Button btn5 = new Button("change");
            
            List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(1,5).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
            
            
            btn5.setOnAction(j -> {
                list.stream().forEach(e -> ocean.stream().filter( p-> p.getX() == 1 && p.getY() == e ).findFirst().orElse(null).putBoatInside());               
            });
            
            root.add(btn, 0, 0);
            root.add(btn1, 1, 0);
            root.add(btn2, 2, 0);
            root.add(btn3, 3, 0);
            root.add(btn4, 4, 0);
            root.add(btn5, 5, 0);
            
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,1200,800);
            
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

BtnOcean class

```java
package GUI;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class BtnOcean extends Button{
    
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private String cssProps = "-fx-background-color:#fff;" +
                              "-fx-border-color:#000000;"+
                              "-fx-border-width: 1px;";
    
    public BtnOcean(int x, int y,String text){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        setMinHeight(60);
        setMinWidth(60);
        setStyle(cssProps);
        setText(text);
    }
    
    public BtnOcean(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        setMinHeight(60);
        setMinWidth(60);
        setStyle(cssProps);
    }
    
    public void putBoatInside() {
        System.out.println(this);
        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#000;");
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: I don't know how can I delete that question... I do what you say for myself and it works, so I found the problem after 2h searching... Somewhere in my code, I lose the references of the boxes.  @kleopatra

Comment: Let that be an excellent learning experience, then. Had you originally posted a [mcve] we could have saved you those 2 hours of searching. :) There's usually a good reason we often ask people to read the FAQs here.